# Is there a German version of the Message Bible?

Tags: bible, bible-translation

Is there a German translation of the Message Bible?  I've read other German versions, but I can't find something as vivid and contemporary.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Not currently**.

According to [Worldcat.org](http://www.worldcat.org/title/message-the-new-testament-in-contemporary-language/oclc/50606400/editions?referer=br&sd=desc&start_edition=1&se=yr&qt=show_more_yr%3A&cookie=&editionsView=true&fq=&fc=yr%3A_25) (links to the original new Testament version, for expansion including Psalms and Proverbs see [here](http://www.worldcat.org/title/message-the-new-testament-psalms-and-proverbs/oclc/39456018/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true), for complete Protestant canon Bible see [here](http://www.worldcat.org/title/message/oclc/991450184?referer=di&ht=edition)), the Message version has only been published in English.